# Remove rows with a value of null

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have some html tags below. The table formed has some null values. Can we remove the rows that has null values dynamically?. Below is the standard format. So some table has no null values and hence 2 rows are required. Some table has null values and hence need to be removed

```html
<div style="background-color: #cbe6ef; padding: .5em; text-align:center">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <b>Tag</b>
            </td>
            <td>
                <b>Number of Reviews</b>
            </td>
            <td>
                <b>Share of Reviews</b>
            </td>
            <td>
                <b>Click for Reviews</b>
            </td>
            <tr>
                <td>A</td>
                <td>B</td>
                <td>C</td>
                <td>D</td>
                <tr>
                    <td>null</td>
                    <td>null</td>
                    <td>null</td>
                    <td>D1</td>
                </tr>
            </tr>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

I tried with below but still not working

```html
<div style="background-color: #cbe6ef; padding: .5em; text-align:center">
<script>
    const x = () => {
        for (const i of document.querySelectorAll('*')) {
            if (i.innerHTML.trim() == 'null') {
               i.innerHTML = ""; <table><tr>(...)</tr></table>
            }
        }
    };
    setInterval(x, 1000);
</script>
```

Comment: If you want to remove null after the document is rendered, then have to use JavaScript

Comment: Can you help me please :)

Comment: Why not simply remove them from the markup, if you don't need them?

Comment: No No. these are standard and need to be dynamic

Comment: What do you mean by "these are standard and need to be dynamic"? That's pure static markup you've shown

Comment: sure @user11740857

Comment: Side note: your HTML is quite messy, I tried to format it better but I did not fix the errors, which are: (1) You should use `style="..."` instead of `style=\"...\"` (do not use 'escape' backslash characters), (2) You should close every `<tr>` tag before a new one is started, or when you do it, it is done too late.

Comment: Please share more details. What do you want to achieve at the end? That rows get deleted if they have a single `null` string within them? That rows get deleted when all columns contain `null`?

Comment: Right . That rows get deleted if they have a single null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily remove rows that have null values using this.

```js
document.querySelectorAll("td").forEach((item) => {
  if (item.textContent.includes("null")) {
    item.parentElement.remove();
  }
});
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/null-remove-7qkgm

Let me know if you need further support.

Answer (score 1):

Try this-

```
<script>
    const x = () => {
        for (const i of document.querySelectorAll('*')) {
            if (i.innerHTML.trim() == 'null') {
                i.parentNode.removeChild(i);
            }
        }
    };
    setInterval(x, 1000);
</script>
```

Comment: Small ask again, right now it is removing only null values . But last column has some value right so it is getting displayed. Can we remove the row it self if it contains a  null value. So basically 2nd row and last column should also be not displayed

Comment: Glad you liked it! It's my first answer on stackoverflow, I'm not sure how it works but could you approve this answer so it shows a green tab

Comment: It is possible, in the line i.innerHTML = ""; Just change it to i.style.display = 'none';

Comment: I tried but not happening.                                                                                             
  ````
<script>
    const x = () => {
        for (const i of document.querySelectorAll('*')) {
            if (i.innerHTML.trim() == 'null') {
               i.innerHTML = i.style.display = 'none'; /* Or whatever you want to do */
            }
        }
    };
setInterval(x, 1000);
</script>````

Comment: Okay hold on, I'll just modify my post

Comment: Hi . you mentioned to put ```` / Or whatever you want to do */ ````. I pasted my code there but still not working. I have edited my question below

Comment: That's a javascript comment, it starts with a /* and you started it with a /. It'll give an error. I added it just for convenience, wait I'll remove all the comments

Comment: I tried with your latest post. Still the last row is there :(

Comment: .style.display = 'none' doesn't actually remove the row, it hides it and also removes the space it took on the screen. If you want to completely remove element, try this: i.parentNode.removeChild(i); I've edited my answer, kindly check it